# RESTful Architecture Authentication/Authorization Strategy

Tags: web-services, security, rest, web, architecture

I'm working on creating an app using Angularjs and Node.js(hapijs specificially).

I'm trying to determine a good authentication and authorization strategy for a RESTful type of architecture like this.

I've spent a lot of time reading the net about this and I came up with a diagram on what i'm proposing doing for my app. I'm wondering if there are any glaringly obvious holes in this model or what I could do to make it even more secure.

This is assuming all traffic is running over SSL. I also can't use SAML or OAuth or anything like that at the moment because this is for an internal application.

[image: RESTful Architecture Model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the second diagram, use 403 for the authorization error and 401 for unauthenticated - that way the client can know which code path to take in handling the error.

It's not clear what the first diagram is showing - if thats the browser requesting the HTML page, you need to return a redirect rather than a 401... the browser won't know what to do with 401.  If that's a call to some /login API, it's fine.

Comment: Sorry the first diagram is showing the login process

Comment: still not clear what you mean but my answer covered both possibilities :)

Comment: Yes your answer does cover both possibilities. When a user is on the login page and enters their username and password and hits submit, my first diagram is supposed to represent what happens from that point.

Comment: ok yeah, if that is an HTML form submission the server needs to return 200 with HTML.  if it's an AJAX call, the 401 is appropriate

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for the service side here?  Is this all directly in MongoDB?  If not, your application layer almost definitely has better session management than you will be able to write.  I would highly recommend you investigate what your platform provides out of the box before you try and write your own.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure exactly what you mean or what part you are referring to. This is a REST architecture so it's STATELESS. Every requests gets authenticated and authorized. Mongo stores a random token and every request from the client contains that token (once the user is logged in and the token is generated). In my case the token is stored on the client in sessionStorage but could just as easily be stored as a cookie.

Comment: It isn't stateless. You have an auth token.  that is state.  You are storing that state in mongodb as your session store.  Let me ask you this.  Does the session last forever?  Do you ever need to time-out their session (token)?

Comment: I guess i always understood stateless as needing to authenticate/authorize every single request that comes to the server. Currently sessions last forever as far as the server is concered. Eventually they will probably time out. When a client closes their browser their sessionStorage is gone and therefore no token exists on the client so they will need to relogin.

Comment: Most session management systems use a cookie as the session key (as you are doing).  They just also handle things like session timeout, mapping additional attributes, explicit session destruction, redirection, etc...  You are just rolling your own.  Depending on the platform you are using (java, php, asp.net, etc), most platforms will handle things like redirecting you to a login page automatically.  This frees you to deal with application logic, not having to handle session management on *every* call to the application layer.